# escuchar todo lo que entre en el puerto 80 y en base a la url redireccionar a distintos jsp

Tags: java, jsp, socket

necesito desde una app (todo esto en java) escuchar siempre lo que viene por el puerto 80 y capturar su url, una vez tenga el url debo redireccionar a un jsp.

desde una aplicacion en aws cuando ocurre un error o el cliente entra en un sitio que no quiero que entre (por la razon que sea) debe llamar a esta app que debe estar escuchando lo que venga por el puerto 80, una vez capturada la url debo derigir a un jsp que contiene la pagina de error

Bueno, gracias a los primeros comentarios, es mi primera pregunta y quiero dejar todo lo mas claro posible.

desde una clase servidor con socket capturo lo que venga por el puerto 80, esta clase tiene el método main y en otra aplicacion tengo el jsp con la pagina de error. no se si lo que tengo hasta el momento esta bien, osea desde otra clase de prueba (cliente) me conecto al servidor y funciona, pero como le hago para desde el socket redirigir al jsp, osea cuando el cliente en su casa cómodamente este viendo la pagina principal (que esta en aws) y le da error 404, ese detonante hace que llame al servidor (192.168.0.1 puerto 5000 ej.), el servidor toma esto por el puerto X, rescata la url (www.miapp.cl/pagos/checkout/validar) y redirecciona la pagina del cliente a mi appmsg.jsp el cual contiene el mensaje de error.

intente con URLConnection, pero solo muestra el contenido de la pagina en cmd.

espero esto pueda ayudar mas.

Comment: Hola @RaulAravena, Bienvenido , que haz intentado? , podrias ver [ask], para tratar de mejorar tu pregunta y siempre es bueno ver que avances tiene uno , para que sea aceptada por la comunidad de SOe , Saludos.

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!